# Expanding Equation with Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How do I expand this equation: $(1+t+t^2)^5$

I formed the equation into a binomial equation this way: $(1+t+t^2)^5=\sum \binom{5}{r_1}\binom{5-r_1}{r_2}t^{r_2}t^{2r_1}$

But I cannot remember how to continue from here to solve for the $r_1$ and $r_2$ terms from here and then to further expand it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll actually need to use [multinomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialSeries.html) here....

Comment: But how do I find out the $r_1$ and $r_2$ before I could carry out the multinomial expansion? Actually, this is the first time I'm seeing this multinomial. I formed into this binomial equation by splitting the $t$ up into two parts and then further split them, which is why now I have these 2 unknowns $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: @xEnOn: You can do it this way by setting the lower bound of $r_2$ to  zero and its upper bound to $5-r_1$. Then the bounds for $r_1$ are 0 and 5. After all, in order for both binomial coefficients to be defined you need $0\le r_2\le 5-r_1$ and $0\le r_1\le 5$. The bounds on the *inner sum* will necessarily depend on the summation variable of the *outer sum*.

Comment: If you were intended to exclusively use binomial coefficients, @Jyrki's is the way to go; on the other hand, going through that route has been confusing for me, and I use what yunone wrote in his answer.

Comment: Hint:

$$(1+t+t^2)^5=(1+[t+t^2])^5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [trinomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion), a specific case of the multinomial formula. Your formula would then be
$$
(1+t+t^2)^5=\sum_{i,j,k}\binom{n}{i,j,k}1^it^j(t^2)^k
$$
for $i,j,k$ nonnegative, where $i+j+k=5$. It's then just a matter of finding all possible sums and plugging in.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $(1+t)$ as $a$ and $t^2$ as $b$. Then solve by using same binomial formula.

Your answer after simplifying will be:

$$1+5t+15t^2+30t^3+45t^4+51t^5+45t^6+30t^7+15t^8+5t^9+t^{10}$$

Hope this will help you